# Javascript onclick window.open doesnt work

Tags: javascript

i got issue with javascript window.open function.

This code works: `onclick=window.open(this.href);`

And this doesn't: `onclick=window.open(this.href, "", "width=200, height=100");`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also read the doc [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Comment: a whole code: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if(is_category("video")) { echo 'onclick="window.open(this.href, "", "width=200, height=100");"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open(this.href, "", "width=200, height=100");
}
```

Also, If `onclick` is HTML attribute then you should use below code.

```
 onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'width=200, height=100');"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around attribute values with spaces in them, currently the attribute value is ending after `this.href,` so the JavaScript cuts cut off mid-statement. This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

(Modern code would use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to bind event handlers instead of using intrinsic event attributes though).

Comment: It's also possible that he *really* wants a function wrapped around the whole thing, no?

Comment: @Pointy — That would be another solution, but I don't get the impression that is particularly what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes:

```
onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'width=200, height=100');"
```

Comment: If the issue really is a **JavaScript** issue, and that code is not actually an HTML element attribute, then using a string won't work.

Comment: @Pointy — I can't think of any circumstance where the first line would work but the second wouldn't other than if `onclick` was an HTML attribute.